# Views, blocks and template?

Tags: drupal, drupal-blocks, drupal-templates

I have a block view called: "MYVIEW"
And I have a region on my template called: "right".

What must I call the template file to edit this?

The following does not work.

- block-MYVIEW.tpl.php
- block-right--MYVIEW.tpl.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you are editing a view in Drupal's administration, you have something like "Thème: Informations" *(my install is in french, so it might be a bit different for yours)* in the section of the screen that correspond to "base parameters" *(same remark)* ; it's the section of the left of the screen, and that entry is near the bottom of the options you can configure.

If you click on the "informations" link, it will display a list of all names you can use for templates files related to that view ; you mimght way to try using one of those ;-)

The module [Theme developper](http://drupal.org/project/devel) might also help you with that kind of stuff, btw.

Comment: I tried that, but those are all for editing the default VIEW template... not BLOCK template. Looking at theme developer quickly.